# javascript file local import is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
-projectName
  --Web Pages
    ---web.jsp
  --js
```

In the console I got something like this

[image]

and this my import stament, i download the dataTables and other jquery file in the js folder.

```
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: are you including jquery before your import statement ?

Comment: Your local host support https?

Comment: sorry, about the edited the error @thescion

Comment: `Failed load resource to http://localhost:8084/ProjectTek/css/jquery.dataTables.js` Why is `jquery.dataTables.js` being requested from `css` folder?

Comment: As the guset said, try to load the script from `<script src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: i just copy paste the wrong error, i already tried to do that also @thescion but it still wont work :(

Comment: It looks to me like `jquery.dataTables.min.js` is getting loaded fine. It is the css file that is not getting loaded. The error regarding `jquery.dataTables.min.js` is because the JQuery library must be loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

Check your actual path of js file. Make sure that you have linked jquery library file.

Answer (score 0):

The console errors that you are showing don't have anything to do with the jquery.dataTables.min.js file being missing.  It looks like that file is getting loaded just fine.  You are missing a related css file:
    css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

You need to put that in your /css directory.

You are also missing the jQuery library, itself.  You are getting a script error from dataTables after it's loaded because it's a jQuery plugin that relies on having jQuery installed before instantiating dataTables.  It appears that you don't have jQuery installed.

So you need to:

- Put jQuery in your /js directory (get it at jquery.com)
- Put jquery.dataTables.min.css in your css directory (get it at www.datatables.net)
- include jQuery in your HTML with an HTML 'script' tag
- include jquery.dataTables.min.css in your HTML like you would any other css file